# How to specify less than version in Gem Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to specify factory_girl_rails version less than 3.0 as I don't have ruby 1.9 installed and 3.0 isn't compatible with 1.8.x. I've tried a few ways round but it always tries to install 3.0.0 and fails on the ruby dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#rails-3-requires-at-least-ruby-1-8-7), Rails 3.0 should still be compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 (they aren't dropping Ruby 1.8 support until 4.0).

But, if you put this in your Gemfile, bundler should use the latest 2.3 version (the last minor version before 3.0) of Rails:

```
gem 'rails', '~>2.3'
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam it's factory_girl_rails gem I'm trying to limit to < 3.0 not rails but same principle should apply. I tried   
gem "factory_girl_rails", '~> 2.0.0'
but it still tried to install factory_girl_rails 3.0.0

Comment: Whoops, not sure how I missed that detail. Hmmm, specifying "factory_girl_rails", '~> 2.0.0' worked for me. I did notice that factory_girl_rails has a dependency on factory_girl version 3.0. Is it possible that's the one that's failing? If so, maybe the version restriction should go against that gem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just managed to get it working by installing  factory_girl -v 2.6.4 followed by factory_girl_rails -v 1.7.0